# Modifying an array property of a resource (participant) during a transaction

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to modify a property of a participant which is an array of relationships during a transaction.

Let's assume I have a user that holds an array of keys like so:

```
participant User identified by userId {
    o String userId
    --> Key[] keys
}

asset Key identified by keyId {
    o String keyId
}

transaction modifyUserKeys {
    --> User user
}
```

Then in the transaction processor function I modify the array (as in adding and removing elements in it) and update the participant:

```
function modifyUserKeys(tx) {
    let user = tx.user;

    // create a new key via factory 
    var newKey = ...

    user.keys.push(newKey);

    return getParticipantRegistry('com.sample.User')
    .then(function (participantRegistry) {
        return participantRegistry.update(user);
    });
}
```

In the [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/common-resource.html) I saw a method called `addArrayValue()` which adds an element to an array. Now I'm unsure whether I'm meant to use this over conventional array manipulation like in my example.

What purpose does this `addArrayValue()` method have and am I able to e.g. remove elements from `keys` via `keys.pop()` or is it restricted to just the addition of new elements like the documentation suggests?

Comment: you can use conventional (`push/pop`) if you like and as you've done, but `newKey` would need to be `newRelationship()` see - useful example -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/fund-clearing-network/lib/clearing.js#L151 in Composer sample networks -  `addArrayValue()` is also validating that it does not violate the model

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's also a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use conventional (push/pop) if you like (and as you've done on the array),  but `newKey` would need to use `newRelationship()`

a useful example similar to what you're trying to achieve is here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/fund-clearing-network/lib/clearing.js#L151 in Composer sample networks - `addArrayValue()` is also validating that it does not violate the model